# I am trying to connect PowerBI to a REST API (Pardot to be specific) and I need to use a POST request. Where do I begin?

Tags: json, salesforce, powerbi, pardot

PowerBI POST request? How can I pull data into PowerBI using a POST query?

Tried to use common connectors in PowerBI but nothing suitable.

Sample code given by Pardot:

POST https://pi.pardot.com/api//version/3/do/// HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Pardot api_key=, user_key=

Comment: http://pardot.topowerbi.com/

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here will be authenticating and then processing data.  Pardot's API isn't really REST, so you will have some additional challenges.

You can POST the authentication request, store the 60min valid token, and then GET and parse the paginated responses.

It will require some manual work on your end to tie in the various pieces that you are looking for, but it is possible (assuming the data you want is exposed by the API).